# Show that, there do not exist two consecutive perfect numbers.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, perfect-numbers

Show that, there do not exist two consecutive [perfect numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number)
I know that it is unknown whether there exist any odd perfect number(s) or not. 
Also, I know that all the even perfect numbers are determined by Euler's theorem. 
Which states that:

> *If $N$ is an even perfect number, then N can be written in the form $N =
>  2^{n−1} (2^n − 1)$, where $2^n − 1$ is prime*

But, still, I am unable to crack the above-mentioned problem asked in some olympiad, I guess.

Any progress is appreciated. Please help with the ideas. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wikipedia lists many necessary conditions for an odd perfect number. Maybe, this helps to rule out numbers of the desired form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $E$ and $P$ are consecutive perfect numbers with $E$ even. Since $5$ and $7$ are not perfect, $E\ne 6$. Then from Euclid's formula, $E$ is $4$ (mod $12$).

First suppose that $P>E$ and then $P$ is $2$ (mod $3$). Let $x$ be any divisor of $P$ and consider $y=\frac{P}{x}$. Then $xy$ is $2$ (mod $3$) and so $x+y$ is $0$ (mod $3$). Thus the divisors of $P$ can be paired so the sum of each pair is divisible by $3$. Hence $\sigma (P)$ is divisible by $3$ and so $P$ is not perfect.

Now suppose $P<E$ and then $P$ is $3$ (mod $4$). The same argument proves that $\sigma (P)$ is divisible by $4$ and so, again, $P$ is not perfect.

Answer (score -2):

Your question/problem is covered exactly in the following [M. Sc. thesis, completed in 2008](https://arxiv.org/abs/1204.1450), at De La Salle University - Manila.

You may refer to pages 53 to 55.

Basically, the following facts about perfect numbers are used:

- A number $M$ (odd or even) satisfying $M \equiv 2 \pmod 3$ cannot be perfect.
- An **odd perfect number** $N$ must satisfy $N \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.

The proof proceeds by first showing that if $O$ is odd and perfect, then $O - 1$ and $O + 1$ cannot be a(n) (even) perfect number.  Next, supposing that $E$ is even and perfect, we show that $E - 1$ and $E + 1$ cannot be a(n) (odd) perfect number.

This completes the proof.

Comment: Care to explain the quick downvote?

Comment: Surely the second fact ($E-1$ and $E+1$ not perfect) is implied by the first ($O-1$ and $O+1$ not perfect)?

Comment: No, @TonyK, the implication does not follow.  I presented the proof in that way so as to ensure that an even perfect number and an odd perfect number cannot differ by $1$.

Comment: @TonyK:  You may refer to the papers by Luca, and Holdener, et. al for more details.  The part of my thesis that I quoted in this answer is basically an exposition of their results on this topic.

Comment: I don't need to refer to any papers to see that the first of those facts implies the second.

Comment: As stated by @TonyK there is no need to repeat the argument both ways round. Furthermore there is no need for reference to a thesis or papers of Luca et al. All that is needed is standard results and the clever trick of Judy A. Holdener.

Comment: No one explains their downvotes. Except me. I didn't do it.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: I explained why the question was flawed. Then the OP refused to engage my comment. _Then_ I downvoted.

Comment: @TonyK: Evidently, as you can plainly see, I **did not refuse** to engage your comment.  Opinions differ, we agree to disagree.